# How to submit img src with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have set up a form like this:

```
<%= form_for xxx.new do |f| -%>
    <%= text_field_tag :num %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :url %><br />
    <%= image_tag("/assets/some_image.png", id: "img")%><br />
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end -%>
```

On submitting the form I can get the text in the xxxController with `params[:num]` and `params[:url]`. Is there a way to get the image's `src` in a similar way? Also, the `src` will change depending on which image the user chooses, so hard coding a solution is not a viable option.

Comment: No. Images are not form elements, their `src` attribute is not submitted with the form. You'll need to use JavaScript to move the image's `src` attribute into an `<input type="hidden">`.

Comment: is your objective to send images to your model? or just the image src? sending the src seems like an odd thing to do... specially because in production the image name will contain a hash in it.

Comment: @TheFabio Yea I just found that out. I just want the `src`, but I am getting `{"image"=>"assets/some_image.png"}` saved to the model. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Let me see if I understood it right... is your intention to allow your users to upload images from their computer?

Comment: @TheFabio I have some images on my app, and I want to get the src of the image the user selects. I solved it by instead of using `<%= hidden_tag(:image_selected, :image) %>` I used `<%= text_field_tag(:image_to_edit) %>` and just made it hidden with CSS. For some reason the value stored in `hidden_field` elements is a JSON datatype, but in `text_field` elements they stay strings.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is make a set of radio buttons with labels that contain images. The user can then click the image to select the radio button.

```html
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="dog" />
    <img width="300" src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/50000/nahled/dog-1373273591Tqi.jpg" />
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="cat" />
    <img height="200" src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/50000/nahled/cat-looking-up.jpg" />
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="moose" />
    <img width="300" src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/40000/nahled/portrait-1365857069JPb.jpg" />
  </label>
</p>
```

When the form is submitted, you get the value of the selected radio button just like everything else. I've made it the name of the animal here, but you could make it match the URL of the image if you like.

With CSS, you can do some nice things like

- Make the cursor a hand when you hover
- Draw a border around the selected image
- Hide the radio button itself